# Accessing a Page Factory's declared Using

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using C#, suppose I've declared a web element as follows

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "foo")]
private IWebElement bar { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to access this element's locator, "foo" inline using the element?

Something like

```
string locator = bar.GetTheUsing
```

Comment: You mean get the `Using` value on its `FindsBy` attribute?

Comment: Seems like that's what I'm looking for, @FurkanKambay , thanks!